# Change type of variable with a for loop

Tags: r

I have a data set in R and I want to turn the first three columns into a factor with a for loop. What I did is:

```
newvar=names(data)[1:3]
for(v in newvar){
    data[,v] = as.factor(data[,v])
  }
```

this works fine. Can anyone tell me why

```
for( v in newvar){
 data$v=as.factor(data$v)
}
```

won´t work?

Comment: Because `$` can't evaluate RHS. Let me use my Google-foo for a sec...

Comment: For what it's worth, you could get around this with the `[[` notation. For example `for (v in newvar) data[[v]] <- as.factor(data[[v]])`

Comment: @brittenb they already got around it AFIK